# my Rspec test keeps failing but it looks like it should work

Tags: ruby, rspec

Here is the test:

I define the key data here:

```
  let('bot_response') {
    {'bot_response' => 'the response contains <SETPROFILE><KEY>test_key</KEY><VALUE>TEST-SETPROFILE-VALUE</VALUE></SETPROFILE>'}
  }
```

I run the method I want to test here:

```
let('bot_response') {BotResponse.act_on_set_profile_tag(
    value,
    bot_client_id,
    bot_response
  )}
```

I assert the test condition here:

```
expect(bot_response['bot_response']).to eq("the response contains")
```

Here is the key part of the actual method:

```
bot_response['bot_response'] = bot_response['bot_response'].gsub(/<SETPROFILE>(.*)<\/SETPROFILE>/, '').strip
return bot_response
```

My test fails with the following:

```
 Failure/Error: expect(response['bot_response']).to eq("the response contains")

   expected: "the response contains"
        got: "the response contains <SETPROFILE><KEY>test_key</KEY><VALUE>TEST-SETPROFILE-VALUE</VALUE></SETPROFILE>"
```

But I cannot figure out why.  I am new to rspec and actually am not sure if I am doing it right, particularly the `let`

Answer (score 2):

```
expect(response['bot_response']).to eq("the response contains")
```

The test above expects the two strings to be the same. If you want to check against a part of the string, try:

```
expect(bot_response['bot_response']).to include("the response contains")
```

See [RSpec matchers](http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-0/docs/matchers/include-matcher) for other options.

Comment: I want them to be the same.  It should strip out what is in the tag.

Comment: Oh, I misread your question. Can you post the spec code in a continuous manner and the method you are testing. You can remove the irrelevant sections. I'm asking because there are two `let(bot_response) { ... }` statements, one bot_response['bot_response'] assignment.